# Cannot select my Android client in DDMS perspective of eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator, ddms, performance

I want to check my program code for time consuming operations. I thought DDMS is the best tool to achieve that.

However, I cant see Threads, Heaps and so on. It tells my to select a client. But I dont know where other than the Devices Tab, which doesnt take effect.

What do I have to do? Is there maybe smth wrong with my ADB setup (But LogCat works fine)?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Don't you usually have to select the 'Update threads' button? (Located next to the 'Stop' button in the DDMS view).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the screen shot, you have the device ("emulator-5554") selected.  You need to click on your application from the list of processes.

For example, if you click on "com.android.music", you will see information about the Music app.

Note that, on a real device, you must mark your application as "debuggable" or it won't appear in the list at all (on an emulator, all apps are debuggable).  See the [Developing on a Device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) page for details.

Comment: Thank you! It works like that: 1. Select Thread 2. Click Button "Heap" or "Thread" on Devices tab.